# BlueStacks and unity 3d?

Tags: android, android-emulator, unity-game-engine, bluestacks

i am trying to test android project developed in unity to be tested via BluStacks emulator since i don't have an android device. While trying to develop android project, i followed the ways like setting java sdk, android sdk, added sdk path, set the bundle identifier. I solved errors in the monodevelop like unrecognized variable and finally got the .apk file. I have successfully installed it in both android emulator and BlueStacks emulator. Now, when i click the installed app in the android emulator, it says "Unfotuately b has stopped", here b indicates my product name of the installed app. On the other hand,when i click the installed app in the BlueStacks,it says "BlueStacks Frontend has stopped working". When i search through the google, all it says reinstalling the BlueStacks, about graphics card problem etc. But i have installed it right and can play other online installed applications. I can not even find the logcat that could give me details about the error. When i search through the google, all i find about the logcat is involving the eclipse. But how can i set the adb logcat while my game development involves unity and BlueStacks instead of Eclipse and BlueStacks? Here i can say that there is less likely any problem with the BlueStacks emulator since i can play the online games and applications with it. I have been trying hard, please somebody knowledgeable give me your valuable suggestions.

Comment: With android sdk and all the settings done properly i can play it in the unity player and get the .apk file, install the .apk in the emulator except i can't play it.